# Js newbie here. I wan't my passwords to include at least: 1 capital, 1 special character

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I wanted my passwords to include at least: 1 capital, 1 special character
I am trying with this while loop to meet the requirements. What am i doing wrong?

```
const characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#$!-_";
const capital = /ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/;
const special = /#$!-_/; 

function PWord (){
      let pass = ""
      while(!((capital.test(pass)) && (special.test(pass))) ){
        for (i=0; i<=11; i++)
        {
          let rand_char = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*characters.length));
          pass = pass + rand_char;
        }
        
        return pass
      }
}

for(let i=0;i<=3;i++){
  let ps = PWord();
  console.log("Password" + (i+1) + ":" + ps);
}
```

Comment: Its not a good idea to handly passwords in the frontend like that

Comment: @Elias We shouldn't assume that this is frontend code, since it could easily be NodeJS.

Comment: "Js newbie here" doesnt sound like using nodeJS

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Comment: It's not part of a project.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I see here is your use of `return` in the while loop. `return` will always end the execution of the entire function and return the specified value. The condition in your loop will only be checked once since you're returning before giving it the chance to check and run again. Try moving that line outside of the loop.